# Function as condition in for loop - does anyone write like this in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, c11

I'm re-discovering C after years of using high level languages like C#, Java and I'm messing around with generic-like functions, I'm trying to write something like functors etc.

I wrote something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int test(int x){
    return (x < 5) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; test(i); i++){
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So it works. The question is: **does anyone write like this in C?**

Opinion-based free version: **does writing like this happen among professional C programmers (operating systems, databases, standard libraries source code)**?

Is this considered as bad practise, not popular, or not very useful for some reasons?

Example above is silly, but actually I'm messing around with object-oriented programming in C and I would like to use something like this in a generic-like function and pass `test(some_struct_t)` function as argument.

Comment: This is really an opinions based question so a bit off-topic. But perhaps you can start by thinking thru and explaining to us what you see the advantage of that code is over a simple `i < 5`?

Comment: The simple answers, in order asked. Yes, a matter of opinion, and not relevant since the perceived lack of popularity in this context is based on *your* familiarity exclusively. It is definitely used, and one need look no further than the most-common usage patterns of `fgets` in controlled loops to see such an example. In your specific case, with your specific function, it is ultimately pointless, as kaylum has pointed out. But function results as loop condition expressions are certainly not rare.

Comment: @WhozCraig This is actually an answer to my question...

Comment: In general, it is perfectly acceptable to use a function as a control expression of a `for` loop.  In fact, there is at least one function in the standard library that is designed to be used that way: `strtok` (although as the first and third expression, not the second).

Comment: Not necessarily a matter of opinion - But rather a matter of performance. You need a pretty clever compiler to understand that the function call actually boils down to (i < 5) and that it could completely optimize out the function call/return overhead of your version.

Comment: @tofro Oh, they [do](https://godbolt.org/z/vGd3qMeMr) ;)...

Comment: Functors can be used but not on such a low level as replacing simple expressions. The right question to ask: what problem does this function solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course functions are used in while loop conditions (no matter if `while` or `for` is used).

```c
WidgetIterator wi = ...;
Widget w;
while ( WidgetIterator_next(wi, &w) ) {
   process_widget(w);
}
```

Not for something silly like the example you gave, though. `(x < 5) ? 1 : 0` is a weird way of writing `x < 5`, and using a function for just `x < 5` simply obscures things. That's not good. It's antithetical to good programming practices.

Comment: I know that my example is silly, I just tried to make my question more useful for others. I actually want to use it with iterator, but I need the index so I decided to use `for` instead of `while`. And for loop with condition seemed strange to me.

Comment: `for` and `while` are both while loops. I could have used `for ( WidgetIterator wi = ...; WidgetIterator_next(wi, &w); )`